Should I interprete data as noise or not
I am tackling a classification problem with 3 classes. Here is what those classes look like on the Two first principal axes.

I fine-tuned a SVM model and the best performance achievable was 50%. By predicting always one of the 3 classes, I achieve 43%. My question are :

Since I clearly see (With eyes) that data is kind of linearly separable - even if noisy and that the performance of SVM does not increase anymore, could any other method like NN or Tree achieve a better score ? Or Even them would not outperform SVM.
If not, according to you, is there a way to reduce noise in the data without modifying their statistical properties ?

Edit: After response from whuber, i plotted the density according to the two first principal axes. I noticed that those classes are not that separable in the input space dimensions.


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Welcome to Cross Validated? What about if you consider the third principal axis? It is possible to have perfect separation on the second and third axes, despite how it looks on the first and second.

Related

Thank you Dave! Yes I tried this approach but it looks even messier, I think those are the axes displaying the most separation for my data. Also There are no statistical outliers so I think it may be related to inherent noise.

So I read the related question and if I understood, the point was that some distributions necessitate going in a higher dimension to differentiate them. And I think it is the whole role of kernel approach in SVMs. Maybe I should try more flexible learners like NNs since the kernel tuning is limited.

The appearance of this plot might be entirely an artifact of the order of data in your table.  You really need to use a clearer visualization, such as one that uses transparency to resolve overlaps.
